# Passing Named Variables to function to find correct Excel Column

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to pass a list of variables to a function and have it auto assign the variables to the correct column based on the name of the column but I can't figure out what is the best way to do it. The script itself works fine, I used a slightly modified version of it before but I can't figure out how to modify it now. I input the variables "VariableName" and "VariableValue" in place of where I need each one to go.

I was looking at arrays to try and pass it since the name and value are linked but I couldn't get it to work.

```
Function Function_AddToWorkSheet {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Worksheet,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Variable
    )
    $Worksheet = $Excel.worksheets.item($Worksheet)
    $NewLine = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    ForEach($SubVariable in $Variables) {
        For ($AddToSheet_ColumnTick = 1; $AddToSheet_ColumnTick -le $AddToSheet_ColumnCount; $AddToSheet_ColumnTick++) {
            If (($AddToSheet_CurrentSheet.cells.item.invoke(1,$AddToSheet_ColumnTick).value2) -EQ $VariableName) {
                $Worksheet.cells.items.($NewLine,$ColumnTick) = $VariableValue
                continue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `$Worksheet` in as a function parameter, and then immediately overwriting it. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few modifications to your function. It looks like things aren't mapping up correctly between your function parameters and the variable names you're using inside the function definition.

Furthermore, your function is dependent on an `$Excel` variable, defined at a higher scope than the function definition. You should consider passing that into the function as a `[ref]` parameter as well. As it's currently written, the function doesn't currently stand on its own.

```
Function Function_AddToWorkSheet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $Worksheet,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Variable
    )
    $Worksheet = $Excel.worksheets.item($Worksheet);
    $NewLine = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;

    ForEach($SubVariable in $Variable) {
        For ($AddToSheet_ColumnTick = 1; $AddToSheet_ColumnTick -le $AddToSheet_ColumnCount; $AddToSheet_ColumnTick++) {
            If (($AddToSheet_CurrentSheet.cells.item.invoke(1,$AddToSheet_ColumnTick).value2) -EQ $SubVariable.Name) {
                $Worksheet.cells.items.($NewLine,$ColumnTick) = $SubVariable.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}

# 1. Define a variable containing an array of HashTables, with Name and Value properties
$VariableList = @(
    @{
        Name = 'Test';
        Value = 'TestValue';
    }
    @{
        Name = 'Test2';
        Value = 'TestValue2';
    }
    );

# 2. Call function, passing in HashTable
Function_AddToWorkSheet -Variable $VariableList;
```